# swapping tokens via uniswapv2router on kovan network. but transaction always fails

Tags: solidity, uniswap, swaps

I was making a swapping contract where a user could swap tokens using uniswapv2router. I have taken example code from here - https://cryptomarketpool.com/how-to-swap-tokens-on-uniswap-using-a-smart-contract/

I was swapping WETH to doge and getAmountOutMin function gives out min tokens. their contract addresses are:

WETH: `0xB4FBF271143F4FBf7B91A5ded31805e42b2208d6`

DOGE: `0x962Da63FF7a33875b2D4ed47112ADe44B1Db96E7`

However when I tried to swap tokens, it always fails with an error. I have deployed it to Kovan testnet. Any help is appreciated.

Failed transaction is- https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0xcbe5bae9b0bd77ae25f2cb900f1d355090d3f1b90c86c9627e609b06ea176864

Smart contract address is: `0x3801e3e49dc73e2a124ea82ec1327068d1b517d9` (Kovan)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to you not passing value to the call to WETH function in order to deposit ETH and get WETH.
If you check the traces [here](https://goerli.etherscan.io/vmtrace?txhash=0xcbe5bae9b0bd77ae25f2cb900f1d355090d3f1b90c86c9627e609b06ea176864&type=parity#raw) you would see that your contract is contacting the WETH contract but not sending any value (`value : 0x0`).

Comment: So what is the possible solution????

Comment: and here I am swapping weth not converting eth to weth